# My system settings doesnt show full to Adminstration section

Tags: display, resolution

My system settings doesnt show full to Adminstration section ; which contains of About, Time & Date, Parental Control and Universal Access. How to fix or revert this? Im so new to linux. help me please. [image: As you see from the photo is attached . The Administration is barely seen under the screen.]

Answer (score 0):

#### Maximize the Window

In elementary OS, you can double click the title bar to toggle an application as full-screen.
Double click the title bar and it should auto-fit to your screen.

[image: Mouse Shown in Title Bar of System Settings Page]

#### Increase the Display's Resolution

If this has no effect, then your screen resolution is smaller than the minimum height of the *System Settings* window.
You might be able to fix this by increasing your screen's resolution from the *Displays* panel in *System Settings*, which fortunately is not cut off on your screen.

The [Recommended System Specifications](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#recommended-system-specifications) recommend a *1024×768* display.
I've tested with this resolution and the *System Settings* window fits correctly, but will be cut off on the next lower resolution for my screen, *800x600*.

1. Click *Displays*.

[image: Select Displays From System Settings]

This will display a preview of the displays connected to your system.

[image: Displays Panel Showing Two Displays Side-by-Side]

2. Click the settings wheel for your display.

[image: Display Settings Showing Current Resolution]

3. Select a higher resolution from the *Resolution* drop down menu.

[image: Display Settings Showing a Higher Resolution]

4. Click *Apply*.

[image: Dialog Asking if the Display Looks OK]

5. In the dialog that appears, click *Keep This Configuration* to confirm the display's updated resolution.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work in my system settings. The double click feature works on Files, Terminal and etc but not on system settings. How to fix this?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address this, hope it helps.